# Adding a parameter of a class to an array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm currently creating a bit of a project piece which stores data about songs and the record companies that own them. I am currently creating a method called addSong which should take a single parameter (an instance of the Song class), and add the given song to the Company array.

```
public class Song 
{
    String songName;
    String songArtist;
    int songPlayed;
    double songEarned;

    public Song(String name, String artist, int played, double earned) {
        songName = name;
        songArtist = artist;
        songPlayed = played;
        songEarned = earned;
    }

    public class Company
    {
        String companyName;
        String[] companySongs = new String[10];

        public Company(String cName, String[] cSongs)
        {
            companyName = cName;
            companySongs = cSongs;
        }

        void addSong()
        {
            for (int a = 0; a<10; a++)
            {

            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    }
}
```

I am struggling to understand how exactly you would get the value of the song's name (songName) to be added to the String array however, and require a bit of guidance.

Comment: Start by adding the `Song` parameter to your method. Then look up getters and setters. And try work it from there.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a Song to companySongs, you should create an array of Songs, not Strings: `Song[] companySongs = new Song[10];`

In any case, if you want to dynamically add a song each time you call it, it is probably easiest if you use a `List<Song>` instead. `addSong()` should also have a parameter of the object that you wanna pass, namely, `Song`.

Staying with the `String[]` example, since you're passing in the array via the constructor, there is no need to instantiate a `String[]` here: `String[] companySongs = new String[10];` -> `String[] companySongs;`

I updated your code to have the List implementation. Generally, you might want to consider refactoring your code so that the Company class is not nested within the Song class (unless you have a specific reason for doing that).

```
public class Company {
    String companyName;
    List<Song> companySongs;

    public Company(String cName, List<Song> cSongs) {
        companyName = cName;
        companySongs = cSongs;
    }

    void addSong(Song newSong) {
        companySongs.add(newSong);
    }
}
```